# Issue when deploying application to GlassFish Server - mapping issue?

Tags: java, postgresql, orm, glassfish-3

I'm trying to deploy an application to my GlassFish Server environment. I've set it up so that GlassFish creates a connection pool to a postgreSQL database on another server (*not* localhost) where the database is located. I test the connection and then try to deploy the application. It fails with a `java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization` error, and my error log contains the following: http://ideone.com/UlZXut (put it here due to its size). There were other warnings above these, but they only referred to tables already existing.

As according to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beajl/index.html), I thought that the required `sun-cmp-mappings.xml` file (the one I assume would be necessary for this correct mapping) would be automatically generated upon deployment, but it seems I was wrong. Could anyone shed some light on this situation?

My apologies if this is not the absolute best part of SE to post this, but it is related to development tools and I did see a number of related posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error log indicates that you are trying to create table(s) with DOUBLE as a datatype. In Postgresql, that datatype is actually called "[double precision](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)". What happens if you revise the table definition to use "double precision" instead?

Comment: The thing is, I cannot directly control the application and just need to set it up to refer to a specific database. It has several sun-<name>-cmp-mappings.xml files for all of the schemas, but no singular sun-cmp-mappings.xml file. I would have assumed that the several ones would take care of that mapping, but they do not.

Perhaps they are not located in the correct directory? I tried several different placements for them but they yield similar results.

Comment: W.A.G: Did you run the capture-schema command to generate the postgresql-specific DDL? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/container_managed-persistence.htm#beaka

Answer (score 0):

on startup Glassfish tries to create the DB tables for your java code. It fails to do that and it fails to startup.

Check the configuration of your ORM mapper.

Comment: Where would I look up that configuration? I apologize for the ineptness, I'm quite new to J2EE applications and searching through the documentation hasn't been fruitful.

Comment: What's your JPA provider?